# Accessing request payload in V2 DialogFlow fulfillment webhook

Tags: java, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to parse the request sent to a java based fulfillment in V2 of the API. I can't find any example documentation in Java for doing this in V2 of the API (com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.38.0-alpha dependency in my project).

So far I've got as far as writing a very basic Spring MVC controller to accept the request.

How can I parse out the payload in the request, e.g. the parameters that dialog flow sent ?

```
import com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.WebhookRequest;
import com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.WebhookResponse;
import com.google.protobuf.Descriptors;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestRequestRestController {


    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestRequestRestController.class);

    @PostMapping("test1t")
    public WebhookResponse getTest1(WebhookRequest request) {


            System.out.println(request.toString());
            return WebhookResponse.newBuilder().setFulfillmentText("Example reply 1 ").build();

    }
}
```

Comment: Its very simple Json, I have done it in C#, the same concept should apply to java, just create a pojo for the json and use Gson to deserialize

Comment: The issue for me is using the Google API, I was hoping that would do most of the work for me ?

Comment: What do you mean Google API, I thought you are using dialog flow fullfillment

Comment: I've set up a fulfillment in DialogFlow, to call my web service. In version 1 of the dialogflow API (api.ai) the api refers to the request you send over as an object of type Fulfillment, in version 2 of the API (now taken over by google and part of the google cloud api) your method that processes the request gets passed a WebhookRequest, not a Fulfillment.

Comment: Did you found a better solution?

Comment: We ended up hand crafting all the Java POJOs as the Google one's provided were useless.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about `WebhookRequest` and `WebhookResponse`.
The code below code might help you.

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;

@PostMapping("test1t")
public String getTest1(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity) {

    String reqObject = httpEntity.getBody();
    System.out.println("request json object = "+reqObject);

    //Get the action
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(reqObject);
    String action = obj.getJSONObject("result").getString("action");

    //Get the parameters
    JSONObject params = obj.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("parameters");
    String response = "Hello from Java."; 
    return "{'speech': '"+response+"', 'displayText':'"+response+"'}";
}
```

Comment: This answer seems to be the actual solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52461591/2685234 It uses GoogleCloudDialogflowV2WebhookRequest class from google-api-services-dialogflow library